# How send php mail() to user@domain.com from my linux server when mx is another server

Tags: php, email, dns

I want to send mail with PHP like this:

```
mail('user@domain.com','subject','body','');
```

the dns config is :

```
$ttl 86400
domain.com. IN  SOA domain.com. postmaster.domain.com. (
            2011052404
            21600
            3600
            604800
            86400 )
            IN      NS      ksxxxxxx.kimsufi.com.
            IN      MX      10 mx.online.net.
            IN      A       11.22.33.44
www     IN  A   11.22.33.44
dev     IN  A   11.22.33.44
domain.com. IN  MX  20 mx-cache.online.net
```

The mx is not local, but when I send `mail()`, the email arrive in local mailbox.

I used the   `ini_set("SMTP","mx.online.net" );` but always the same.

Any idea ?

EDIT :
It's qmail server.

EDIT2 :
I deleted the line domain.com:domain.com in the file /var/qmail/control/virtualdomains, and it seems to be ok.

Comment: Have you checked the mail log on your system?

Comment: What smtp server are you using? Sendmail? Postfix? Qnail?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sendmail as the mail server on your local machine, then you need to configure your [SMTP relay](http://cri.ch/linux/docs/sk0009.html) on your machine to forward all mail to your mx server, or some otherr external smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with PHP and not much to do with DNS. It's exclusivley about your MTA config - but you've provided no details about this.

> when I send mail(), the email arrive in local mailbox

....

> ini_set("SMTP","mx.online.net" );

If you're using an SMTP connection from your client then there is no such thing as a 'local mailbox'